# Why are Felicity, Cisco, and Caitlin re-introduced to each other in The Flash: Going Rogue?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

When Barry was struck by lightning and went into a coma, Felicity constantly traveled to Central City to visit him at S.T.A.R. labs, where she met Wells, Cisco and Cailtin.  However, in the Going Rogue episode of The Flash, Barry introduces her to Wells, Cisco, and Caitlin, saying, "This is Felicity Smoak, she works with the Arrow".  Why would she need to be re-introduced when she's already spent a substantial amount of time with them from visiting Barry and from their interaction in season 2 of Arrow?

Comment: I don't have a cannon answer for this, but from a production view there are people who watch the Flash and not Arrow so they might not know who Felicity is. And even on Arrow when she was visiting Barry she probably never told them she worked with The Arrow"

Comment: The man making the introductions was in a coma at the time.  It's like introducing your girlfriend to your coworkers, when you didn't realize she used to work there too.  Unless I'm forgetting a line, he simply didn't know they'd met and they were too polite to point out his mistake.

Comment: @JoeyD473 good point, but Caitlin and Cisco knew she works with the Arrow because the two teams worked together before.  Team Arrow worked with them after Deathstroke attacked them and again when the Mirakuru soldiers were attacking the city.

Comment: @Nerrolken I didn't think about that.

Comment: Had Wells met her? I'm only on S1 of Arrow. He introduces the group, but it may be more for Wells' benefit than the others.

Comment: It's never actually shown or said is she and Wells met when she was visiting Barry, but it would be impossible for them not to have.  Barry was transferred to S.T.A.R labs a week after he was struck by lightning and kept a pretty constant, watchful eye on him.  Plus, she's paying pretty regular visits to him in Wells's facility.  If they never met during those 9 months it would be miraculous.  Of course I could be wrong and Barry introducing her could be entirely for Wells's benefit.

Comment: But would any of the people who had specifically met her necessarily mention that she worked with The Arrow?

Comment: That's why I asked this.  Barry, Cisco, and Caitlin have all met Felicity on screen and they all know that she works with Oliver.  So why would Barry need to introduce her to the group as someone who works with The Arrow?  They already know.  You're most likely right though, it was probably for Wells's benefit because this is the first onscreen meeting they have.

Comment: No, they had *no idea* she worked with The Arrow until Barry told them. They also had no idea who The Arrow was -- because they try to get Felicity to tell them and she refuses.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield, um, they work with Felicity a couple of times in Season 2 of Arrow.  The first time is when Slade goes to get his machine thing from STAR Labs, either Cisco or Caitlin speak to Felicity on the phone about Barry being in a coma.  Granted, that doesn't indicate that they know she works with the Arrow.  However, in the S2 pentulant episode, Felicity sends a sample of the Mirakuru to Caitlin and Cisco at STAR Labs so they can make a cure.  In the finale, Felicity gets a call from one of them saying that it's been made and that they're sending a runner with the cure.

Comment: All this is before Felicity shows up in Central City after Barry wakes up.  So yeah, they know that Felicity works with the Arrow, and they had already met her multiple times, again, she had been to Central City multiple times to visit Barry, she also asks Caitlin how Barry's doing when they are in Starling, that's when she first finds out about Iris visiting him as well.  But I never said that they knew who the Arrow was.

Comment: So far, you haven't said anything that proves that they knew she worked with the Arrow, only that she asks them for some very weird favors. And based on their reaction when Barry tells them, all evidence points to them *not* knowing.

Comment: One thing I failed to mention though.  When did I ever say they knew she worked with the Arrow in my original question?  I asked why she was reintroduced.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Out-of-universe, it was a way to prevent viewers who hadn't seen *Arrow* from being confused, while also getting in a nice plug for why they should go check it out.

In-universe, the man making the introductions was in a coma at the time. It's like introducing your girlfriend to your coworkers, when you didn't realize she used to work there too. Unless I'm forgetting a line, he simply didn't know they'd met and they were too polite to point out his mistake.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit late for this, but you've actually got the dialog in the scene a bit wrong. What actually happens is this:

> *Barry walks Felicity into STAR Labs and begins to show her all the cool toys. Caitlin and Cisco walk over...*
>
> Caitlin: It's so wonderful to **see you again** Felicity [emphasis mine], I'm just wondering how much of our operation she needs to know about.
>
> Felicity: I'm really good at keeping secrets.
>
> Barry: Yeah, Felicity works with the Arrow.

As you can see, Barry doesn't "introduce" Felicity to Cisco or Caitlin; it's clear they both already know her. What he does reveal is that she works with The Arrow... something *neither* of them would have known at that point. All they knew up until the was that Barry had gone to Starling City to work a case, that he had met Felicity there, and that she had come visit him while he was in his coma.